# A problem from partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x-y)^2\sin\frac1{x-y}&x\ne y\\0&x=y\end{cases}$$
I have to show that the first-order partial derivatives exist for $f$ at each point $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$.

First I showed it for all $(x,x)$. There, very easily, it can be shown that the partial derivatives exist and are 0. But I could not proceed with the rest of the plane.

Comment: Can't you just do analytic expressions for the partial derivatives where $x\ne y$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For a function of the form $f(x,y) = F(x-y)$, the Chain Rule implies that, if $F$ is differentiable, $\partial_x f(x,y) = F'(x-y)$ and $\partial_y f(x,y) = -F'(x-y)$.

Comment: Can you prove the existence of the partial derivatives. The question here is to prove the existence not to find the value.

Comment: yes I can, and I have hinted at it.

Comment: Your expression does not work for x=y. And what about continuity of the partial derivatives

Comment: @Ritam it does work for $x=y$. And also it works for that as well.